What is the difference between SMB1 and SMB2
why is SMB1 considered outdated while SMB2 is preferred?

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block#History

SMB1 nor SMB2 are secure protocols, they are both insecure standards that have no business being used, ever.

Neither SMB1, nor SMB2 have been preferred for a decade. Almost every SMB, and CIFS client will prefer SMB3.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/file-server/file-server-smb-overview

One of the many advantage of SMB 3.1.1 is the ability to protect against MITM.  SMB3 also supports encryption, and many other things to secure the link.
I don't have links/refs handy, but I remember one of the big improvements between SMB1 and SMB2 was related to improvements to performance over high latency links (WAN).  Earlier versions of SMB were very chatty with lots of acknowledgments, that would cause it to really hurt over higher latency links.
There are lots of details about SMB/CIFS that can be found in the Microsoft publications.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-cifs/d416ff7c-c536-406e-a951-4f04b2fd1d2b
Anyway, you really shouldn't use SMB1, particularly on Windows. This is a pretty good article on flaws of the oldest versions of the SMB protocol.
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/storage-at-microsoft/stop-using-smb1/ba-p/425858
